# Russian letters in php from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

hello i have such output from php

```
????????? ??, 29/06/2014 - 17:50
!username
???????????? ????????:

    --?????? ? ????????????? ??????????--
    ??????????
```

i try `echo utf8_decode($text);`, `echo iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $text);`
`SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+`

can some one help me with my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Try this:-
Add this on the top of your document 

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run just after connecting with MySQL the following query:

```
SET names='utf8'
```

before you make any other queries.

I don't know what method of connections you use but it may be for example:

```
mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Comment: Don't do that! Use [the proper function](http://uk3.php.net/mysqli-set-charset)

Comment: Thanks for info, I didn't know that function exists. Personally I use PDO and not for all versions of PHP/MySQL and connection types it's possible to set charset this way